# Implement a readN() from read7()

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, io

Exercise:

> Using a `read7()` method that returns 7 characters from a file,
>   implement `readN(n)` which reads n characters.
>
> For example, given a file with the content `"Hello world"`, three
>   `read7()` returns `"Hello w"`, `"orld"` and then `""`.

I made a version using `std::deque`. It seems inefficient to me with all the loops to read/write a string, but I couldn't think of an alternative for this FIFO. Any comments on that part would be especially appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <deque>

inline auto read7()
{
  static std::istringstream is("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890");
  char res[8]{};
  is.get(res, 8);
  return std::string(res);
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto& operator<<(std::deque<T1>& deq, const T2& seq)
{
  for (const auto& elm : seq)
  {
    deq.push_back(elm);
  }
  return deq;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto get(std::deque<T2>& deq, std::size_t n)
{
  T1 res;
  while (res.size() != n && !deq.empty())
  {
    res += deq.front();
    deq.pop_front();
  }
  return res;
}

auto readN(std::size_t n)
{
  static std::deque<char> buffer;
  while (n > buffer.size())
  {
    auto old_sz = buffer.size();
    buffer << read7();
    if (old_sz == buffer.size())
      break;
  }

  return get<std::string>(buffer, n);
}


int main()
{
  std::size_t sz;
  while(std::cin >> sz)
    std::cout << readN(sz) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pedantically, none of the included headers are guaranteed to define `std::size_t`.  It is (in principle) possible to implement those headers without defining that type, and we're required to include one of the headers that *does* define it (e.g. `<cstddef>`).

We could avoid the `push_back` loop by using the `std::copy()` algorithm with a `std::back_inserter` as the destination.  More simply, we could just use the deque's `insert()` like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto& operator<<(std::deque<T1>& deq, const T2& seq)
{
    using std::begin();
    using std::end();

    deq.insert(end(deq), begin(seq), end(seq));
    return deq;
}
```

I think the `old_sz` check in `readN()` is less clear than simply checking whether the input chunk is an empty string:

```
std::string s;
while (buffer.size() < n && !(s = read7()).empty()) {
    buffer << std::move(s);
}
```

Or, just inline the `<<`, given that it's a one-liner and not used anywhere else:

```
using std::begin();
using std::end();

std::string s;
while (buffer.size() < n && !(s = read7()).empty()) {
    buffer.insert(end(buffer), start(s), end(s));
}
```

---

On the choice of approach: I probably wouldn't use a deque.  We only need to store a surplus of up to 7 characters, which is fine to hold in a string (most implementations use a "small-string" optimisation to avoid allocating heap space for the characters).  I would implement `readN()` by starting with an empty, `n`-capacity string and building it up in place, storing the new surplus back to the string where we keep it.

Answer (score 3):

Why is `read7` declared `inline`? You should only do this when it's needed as an optimization. (And it's particularly confusing when the function contains a `static` variable.)

It's not necessary for `is` to be static. It should really be an argument to `read7`, so it can work on any `istream`. (In real code, `buffer` should also be a parameter to `readN`, but for this toy problem it's reasonable to have it static.)

Bug: what happens if the input contains null characters?

You could avoid the queue by using a string as the queue. You can simply append the result of each `read7` to it until you have enough characters, then remove and return the first `n`.

Comment: `is` is static because `read7` is supposed to be that magic function that gives you 7 characters. Maybe like `std::getline`

Comment: Removing first `n` characters from string is really inefficient, isn't it? How is this an improvement

Comment: @Ayxan Making it an argument allows you to read from any stream, for example a file.

Comment: @L.F. `read7` is not a part of the exercise. It's a "magic" function that returns 7 characters. If I had the stream in the first place, I would read n characters without the need of `readN`

Comment: @Ayxan Oh, now I understand.  That's a really interesting exercise :)